# Can I format a USB stick in Windows XP, in HFS+ format, and make the USB stick Mac OS X bootable?

Tags: windows, macos, boot, bootable-media, hfs+

My Intel Mac OS X computer is corrupt and I feel at this point that I need to perform a fresh install of the OS.  It consistently and automatically logs out, right after I log in.  I tried logging in as the root. I tried safe boot and it wouldn't load.

Anyway, the point is I want put the Mac OS X installer on a USB flash drive and have it boot up on the Intel Mac OS X computer. Unfortunately, the computer is inaccessible, as I mentioned above.

So, I have a Windows XP machine that I'm using and attempting to create a bootable USB flash drive that's compatible with Mac OS X.

I have tried TransMac, MacDrive, and Paradox for Windows -- all of which proved unable to format the USB flash drive in HFS+. How do I know this?  Well, even though the TransMac reports that ther flash drive has been formatted to HFS+, Computer Management in Windows says otherwise:

[image]

[image]

I even put the installer on the USB drive, after TransMac reportedly formatted it properly, and the Mac OS X computer didn't even recognize that a USB flash drive was inserted, via pressing the option key at boot time.

I'm not sure what the problem is and how to actually format the drive. Can anybody offer any help?

Comment: Why do you believe that Computer Management would be able to identify a HFS+ volume?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mispoke.  I don't mean that it should be able to read HFS+, but I would imagine the File System column would display something other than blank.  In any event, it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: You would only know whether it worked or not after you tried the stick on some system that actually does recognize HFS+. Windows does not (by itself) and so there's nothing it can (or should) display in the File System column. Have you tried to access the USB stick with [HFSExplorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsx.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off downloading a Linux Live CD place it in your cd/dvd player on the XP Machine make sure the USB Drive is attached. Boot the computer ( you my have to enter the BIOS to select the CD/DVD as the first Boot Device) using the Live CD such as Super FDisk so create the HFS+ on the USB Flash drive.

I assuming that you know how to download the LIVE Linux ISO Image and burn it to a disk using the XP Machine. If not post back here and I'll post some tutorials that you can use.

Best of Luck
Mark